# No Cargan estilos boostrap ni css externos en dompdf

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap, dompdf

Ayuda!! Estoy generado un archivo pdf mediante un query  que me genere un archivo PDF con la libreria DOMPDF (Version 2.0.3) pero en el archivo .pdf generado no me trae los estilos de un css externo  ni los estilos boostrap.

Mi codigo

```
    <?php 
    
    ob_start();
    
    ?>
    
    
    
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dependencias/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dependencias/estilos/reporte.css">
    
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       
    
    
 <table class="table table-bordered"> 

 </table>
  
    </body>
    </html>
    
    
    
    <?php
    $html=ob_get_clean();
    //echo $html;
    
    require_once '../dependencias/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
    
    
    use Dompdf\Dompdf;
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    
    $options = $dompdf->getOptions();
    $options->set(array('isRemoteEnabled' => true));
    $dompdf->setOptions($options);
    
    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    //$dompdf->setPaper('letter');
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
    
    $dompdf->render();
    
    $dompdf->stream("hello.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
    
    
    
    ?>
```

Todo el $html lo tengo en variable que la llamo para inicializar el pdf

`$dompdf->loadHtml($html);`

Si me podrian ayudar cualquier seria el problema estaria agradecido

Comment: revisa los ejemplos en su repositorio   https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/tree/master/tests, tambien se basa en `CSS2.1` https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ asi que tendras que echar mano o incorporar los css al html, mira la guia  https://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php,tambien podrias usar webpack para ahorrar tiempo

Comment: Yo tenia entendido que los estilos los tenia el archivo generador, nunca los traía de otros archivos. Claro, hace mucho que no uso DOMPDF...

Comment: de salida yo prefiero mPdf ya que ninguna libreria soporta al 100% BS: mira por [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49165313/22473069) o tal vez por [haca](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/issues/66)

Comment: el objetivo de los PDF es ser lo mas sencillo y liviano posible, y contener informacion por lo meno no facilmente editable.